# Android Выполнять Действие Каждый день

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет. Есть приложения. И нужно чтобы каждые 24 часа или в определенное время приходило уведомления и чистился кеш. Ну допустим выполнялся метод MyTask () Как реализовать это на android java?

Comment: [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(HomeContactActivity.this,
                AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                HomeContactActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // устанавливаем на 10:00 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, //каждые 24часа                               
                pendingIntent);
```

Comment: это вставить в начала? например в StartActivity?